# How to make binding from user control to property of parent control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've seen similar questions, but I still not able to do my need. I need to output checkbox's name through a label inside a user control:

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBinding" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox1">
            <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfBinding.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=Name}"></Label>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

How to do it correctly? What lack of knowledge I have? Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could create a property in your UserControl that gets the parent control's name or whatever.

Comment: If I do it in code-behind, it will not be easily noticed having look at xaml markup. That's why I need a xaml way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above solution will work, but a more direct solution for this specific problem would be to use RelativeSource binding in your user control as below:

```
<Canvas>
     <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Name}"></Label>
</Canvas>
```

Hope this is what you need !!!

Answer (score 1):

`ElementName` binding works within in `same XAML scope`. This will work -

```
 <Grid>
    <CheckBox Name="checkBox1"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

But if you want to do it in different UserControl, you have to tweak a bit your code and use `Tag` to hold name -

```
 <Grid>
    <CheckBox Name="checkBox1">
        <local:UserControl1 Tag="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=Name}"/>
    </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

UserControl.xaml

```
<Canvas>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                       Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

On a sidenote, in your `UserControl`, you know you need to bind with `ElementName = checkBox1` and that's the name only you are binding to. Its something equivalent to -

```
<Label Content="checkBox1"/>
```